# Hiding hyperlink in Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, hyperlink

I has some Heading in Anchor tag  Test heading. So when I move cursor on this heading, I am getting it as underlined text and an cursor point as hand.   I don't want it to appear as a hyperlink anymore (don't want to see the heading underlined and cursor point as hand on H:over), So I applied the changes as

```
.heading a:hover, a:visited, a:link, a:active {CURSOR: none; TEXT-DECORATION: none; color:#FF8000;}
```

I am seeing expected result in the IE and Mozilla but Still I am able to get cursor point as hand in the chrome(where as underlining issue fixed in chrome as well).

Can anyone suggest how to achieve the needful in chrome??

Note: I can't not remove the Anchor tag ( Test heading) as I m using it as a link from some other point

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `CURSOR:default;`

[Cursor options](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_cursor.asp)

A quick example: http://jsfiddle.net/Z763j/3/

Tested in Chrome, IE and FF

CSS

```
.heading a
{
    cursor:default;
    TEXT-DECORATION: none; 
    color:#FF8000;
}
```

HTML

```
<div class="heading"><a href="http://www.superuser.com">THIS LINK</a></div>
```